# Human readable Array/Object data fixtures in Doctrine 1.2 using YAML

Tags: php, doctrine, yaml, fixtures, doctrine-1.2

Is it possible to have fixtures with human readable, unserialized php arrays, without having to serialize them?

Currently I serialize the data, but it's hard to read and edit. If I dump data I receive readable data, but it doesn't seem possible to import.

Schema for the field in question:

```
    template_data: 
      type: object
      default: null
```

This is the kind of entry I currently have in my data-fixtures YAML file. It is serialized (PHP) and works fine when loading fixtures into a database:

```
BannerCampaign:
  BannerCampaign_1:
    name: Frontpage
    description: Frontpage
    template_data: a:1:{s:7:"banners";a:3:{i:0;a:4:{s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:32:"/url/123";s:10:"image_path";s:11:"front_1.jpg";s:3:"alt";s:0:"";}i:1;a:4:{s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:39:"/url/456";s:10:"image_path";s:11:"front_2.jpg";s:3:"alt";s:0:"";}i:2;a:4:{s:6:"target";s:0:"";s:3:"url";s:18:"/url/789";s:10:"image_path";s:11:"front_3.jpg";s:3:"alt";s:0:"";}}}
```

This is the kind of fixtures I get when dumping a database to a fixture file (`doctrine.php dump-data`)

```
BannerCampaign:
  BannerCampaign_1:
    name: Frontpage
    description: Frontpage
    template_data:
      banners:
        -
          target: ''
          url: /url/123
          image_path: front_1.jpg
          alt: ''
        -
          target: ''
          url: /url/456
          image_path: front_2.jpg
          alt: ''
        -
          target: ''
          url: /url/789
          image_path: front_3.jpg
          alt: ''
```

The latter YAML is more readable, but I doesn't seem possible to import the fixtures to a database without the following error:

```
PHP Warning:  unserialize() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in
```

Any idea if what I "hope" is achievable, is in fact, achieveable?